# How to get Specific Value from Session Array in CI?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session-variables

I get the session from :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
exit;
```

and the result is :

```
 Array
 (
   [session_id] => 47fa796fbc6c5146a5ba0b1e596f4354
   [ip_address] => ::1
   [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
   [last_activity] => 1468617532
   [user_data] => 
   [session_data] => Array
     (
        [default] => english
        [register] =>  Register Now 
        [login] =>  Login 
        [logout] => Logout
        [home] => Home
        [latest_event] => Latest Event
        [events] => Events
        [contact_us] => Contact Us
        [submit_event] => SUBMIT EVENT
        [register_now] => REGISTER NOW
        [find_best_event_for_you] => Find Best Event For You
        [select_date] => Select Date
        [find_event] => Find Event
        [create_event_home] => Create Your Own New Event
        [create_event_home_txt] => Bring people together, or turn your passion into a business. Eventbrite gives you everything you need to host your best event yet.
        [select_city] => Select City
        [popular_events] => Popular Events
        [ticket_details] => Tickets & details
        [ticket_from] => Tickets from
        [free] => Free
        [what_you_want] =>  What You Want 
        [message_placeholder_value] => Please write your message here...
        [success_message] => Thank you! Your message has been sent.
        [send] => Send
        [all] => All
        [email] => Email
        [for_get_password] =>  Lost your password? 
    )

[default] => 0
```

)

I only want the value of **`[default] => english`** and not any other array object. I also want to store this in any variable, but I can't figure out how to do that in CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
  //you can access any session data by session name using this // default is a session name
  $session_default = $this->session->userdata('default');

  echo $session_default ; // english
```

**You can also use this**

```
$data = $this->session->all_userdata();

$session_default = $data['session_data']['default']);

echo $session_default ;

// english
```